# How do I flash one word at a time from within a post body to a separate div

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to flash the individual words from within a post body, into a div one word at a time really really quickly.

```
var postbody = document.getElementById('postbody');
var posttext = $('#postbody').text();
var postwords = posttext.split(" ");
for (var i=0; i < postwords.length; i+=1) {
    console.log(i)
    setTimeout(function(i)
    {
        $("#flashreadword").fadeOut("slow", function (i)
        {
            currentword = postwords[i];
            console.log(currentword)
            $("#flashreadword").html(currentword);
            $("#flashreadword").show();
        });
    }, 300);
};
```

Comment: You aren’t waiting for one timeout to complete before you set up the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the little information you've provided, I've created a sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jquery-playground-forked-5pty1m?file=/src/index.js), this reads the inner text of a `postbody` on a click of a button then sets innertext of `flashreadword` every 200ms. I've used async and await you can ofc set timeouts but you may have a condition of running out of sync.

```js
import $ from "jQuery";

$("#submit").click(async () => {
  var posttext = $("#postbody").text();
  var postwords = posttext.split(" ").filter((x) => /[aA-zZ]|[0-9]/.test(x));
  for (var i = 0; i < postwords.length; i++) {
    console.log(postwords);
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 200));
    $("#flashreadword").text(postwords[i]);
  }
  $("#flashreadword").text("ALL WORDS COMPLETED");
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
      <div id="postbody">
        This is my text
      </div>

      <div id="flashreadword"></div>
    </div>
```